# How to use android camera method and the native camera function togather

Tags: android-camera

I am implementing a face recognition and eye blinking to authenticate a user.But I was wondering if you can capture the image with an android function and pass it on to the shared object and during this process the blinking function should capture the eye and monitor the frame for blinking in real time.My question is can I capture the image and use opencv-2.3.1 capture function to capture the frame for template matching at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can offload the processing (with openCV) to a worker thread, then camera preview callbacks will continue normally. If you are using the faster [`setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790566/how-to-get-raw-preview-data-from-camera-object-at-least-15-frames-per-second-in) method, then you should be careful to release your buffer for camera reuse as soon as possible - probably before the image recognition is complete.