# My camera preview is capturing at 1 frame per second

Tags: android, camera, rotation, preview, frame-rate

My application currently has a preview screen and I want it to capture many frames a second
for processing. At the moment, my preview is only storing an image every second, however I require a much larger fps capture rate. Any help would be appreciated.

Another problem (if you can) is that my images are rotated 90 degrees when they appear on my sd card. No internet solutions so far have helped me for these problems :(

Thanks :)

```
    public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
                               int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> size = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.get(0).width, size.get(0).height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){}

        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

                int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();

                //YUV formats require more conversion
                if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
                    int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

                    // Get the YuV image
                    YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(data, format, w, h, null);
                    // Convert YuV to Jpeg
                    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 10, output_stream);
                    byte[] byt = output_stream.toByteArray();

                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                                "/sdcard/bb%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));

                        outStream.write(byt);
                        outStream.close();


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {

                    }

                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();


        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) allows you to set the frame rate with `setPreviewFrameRate`.  The value must be in the range described by `getPreviewFpsRange`.

Second, handling preview frames in a `byte[]` is going to restrict your frame rate severely because of the amount of data that has to be copied around.  If you want to write unmodified full-frame YUV data to disk then you don't currently have a choice.  If you can cope with compression artifacts, and you have Android 4.3 or later, you can just save the data as an MPEG video and read the frames back later.  See the CameraToMpegTest.java sample on [this page](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) for a code example.

Rotating an image by 90 or 180 degrees is straightforward to code.  The `Bitmap` class can do it if you don't want to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`setPreviewCallback()` is an easy, but less efficient way to request preview frames. The main problem is that the framework may be very busy allocating the `byte[]` chunks to fill, and the garbage collector may take a heavy price. The preferred method is to use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()`, but even this does not guarantee desired frame rate, as can be seen in *[How to get raw preview data from Camera object at least 15 frames per second in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790566/how-to-get-raw-preview-data-from-camera-object-at-least-15-frames-per-second-in)*