# Returning null while converting byte[] to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera

I want to Fetch Frames from Android Device camera. I have found answer from CameraTest.java file using link:
[How to get raw preview data from Camera object at least 15 frames per second in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790566/how-to-get-raw-preview-data-from-camera-object-at-least-15-frames-per-second-in)

I edited code inside

```
public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera{
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 
}
```

But I got bitmap value 'null' every time. How can I resolve this issue.
Or How can I fetch frames from camera and stores into bitmap and upload that bitmap.

Comment: AFAIK `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` doesn't understand "raw" format ... what did you set with `setPreviewFormat`? what is a "raw" format?

Comment: Actually I want frames from camera. I have used java file as I have mentioned but I dont know how to fetch frames from camera and put it to bitmap to storing that frames.

Comment: *to fetch frames from camera and put it to bitmap* just don't do this ... operate on the data directly ... Bitmap is too heavy for such tasks like camera preview

Comment: But i want camera frames for uploading to server

Comment: It will be laggy as hell ... send raw data and proccess it on the server ... but even posting simple raw data would be laggy

Comment: Then what could be possible solution for this, I want to make my device camera to live.