# setPreviewCallback() and setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a code that accesses the stream of frames from front camera and pushes them to the processing to background thread. Right now I'm not using any buffers at all and everything works (on my phone).

So the question how `setPreviewCallback()` is different from `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` for this particular task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference for background processing may be significant. The camera buffers may be huge, and `setPreviewCallback()` causes separate allocation for every frame (hopefully, 30 per second). This may become a significant pressure on the JVM, because the buffer is not released immediately (and the GC cannot rely on the young generation optimization).

`setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` reuses pre-allocated buffers, and the GC is involved. This also provides an easy mechanism to get just enough frames for your background processor. For example, if you only pre-allocate 2 frame buffers, then after you have two frames sent for processing, the third frame will not be captured (reducing the CPU usage for copying pixels, too) until you call `addCallbackBuffer()` to release a buffer.

Be careful not fall into the trap of *[extra locks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771003/192373)*: if you release the buffer early, you suffer the overhead of Binder copying the pixels that you actually throw away.